# Inverse $T$ matrix of a 3*3 matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have the matrix
$$ A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I have found the
$$ T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 3/5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
How can I find the $T^{-1}$? I already know the $\frac{1}{|T|}$ part but I am confused with the adjugate matrix.

Comment: What has $T$ to do with $A$?

Comment: it is A=T*D*T^(-1), where D=diag(λ1,λ2,λ3) and T=[V1|V2|v3]

Comment: @Irini In that case your matrix $T$ of eigenvectors is incorrect!

Comment: @Irini: Shouldn't you have $$T = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & 23 \\
 0 & 1 & 20 \\
 0 & 0 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the definition of [adjugate](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Adjugate_matrix#3_%C3%97_3_generic_matrix) are you struggling with? It's the transpose of the matrix whose $ij$-entry is $\det M_{ij}$, where $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of the minor, where row $i$ and column $j$ have been removed. In other words, the number $\det M_{ij}$ is placed in the $ji$-entry of the adjugate.

Comment: ok, I need to re-check the eigenvector that is (1, 1, 3/5) which should have been instead (23, 20, 12), according to Wolfram Alpha. In any case, thanks for the help with the corrections and with the adjugate too :)

Comment: @Irini your second eigenvector (4, 0, 1) is also incorrect, it should be (4, 1 ,0).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way (other than asking Wolfram Alpha) is to do a [**row echelon**](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-precalculus-concepts-2.0/section/8.5/primary/lesson/row-operations-and-row-echelon-forms-pcalc/) reduction on the augmented matrix

$$ U =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 3/5 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right] $$

This gives

$$ V = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 7/5 & \mbox{-}4 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \mbox{-}3/5 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right] $$

which means the inverse is

$$ T^{-1} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 7/5 & \mbox{-}4 \\
 0 & \mbox{-}3/5 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right]$$

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's matrix of eigenvectors is already incorrect... Moo's comment to the post gives the correct matrix $T$.